# How can I compile sqlite3 from source on macOS?

Tags: homebrew, apple-silicon, sqlite

I'm trying to build a copy of `sqlite3` from source on my M1 Mac Mini running macOS Monterey 12.4 (21F79). The reason I want to do this (instead of using a [precompiled build](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) or installing via Homebrew or MacPorts) is that I need to enable the `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` flag (see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit)). It's my understanding that in order to enable that flag, one needs to compile from the [canonical source](https://www.sqlite.org/getthecode.html), rather than the [amalgamation](https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html).

I have read the project's page entitled [*"How To Compile SQLite"*](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html) but I failed to wrap my head around the process. I vaguely understand that I will need some combination of gcc, Tcl, the Lemon parser, a bit of luck, and the right incantations to feed them all.

With regard to that flag, the page specifically states:

> *If this option is defined, then it must also be defined when using the Lemon parser generator tool to generate a parse.c file. Because of this, this option may only be used when the library is built from source, **not from the amalgamation** or from the collection of pre-packaged C files provided for non-Unix like platforms on the website.*

I understand this may be an XY problem! Still, I would like to know how to do this—if only to satisfy my curiosity. Does anyone know the steps?

Comment: We can give a answer listing what to do as @jksoegaard has done but really to satisfy your curiosity you need to break down the parts to study - start with make and gcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to try again in September 2023, and was successful! (SQLite 3.43.1, macOS 14.0, Xcode15.0). Below are the *exact* steps I took for anyone interested.

##### Steps I took

1. Download the [canonical source](https://www.sqlite.org/getthecode.html) (tar.gz) for the specific version you want to build.

   > I elected *not* to use [`fossil`](https://sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/README.md), instead I searched for the commit tagging the version I wanted using this syntax: https://www.sqlite.org/src/timeline?r=version-3.43.1
   > .
   > Then I clicked the *check-in* link and download the Tarball:
   > [image: git]
2. Extract the `SQLite-2d3a40c0.tar.gz` tarball
3. Open a Terminal, `cd` into that directory and run the following commands

   ```bash
   autoconf
   ./configure CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT=1"
   make
   ```
4. if all goes well, a newly-minted `sqlite3` binary (with `ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT`) should be in the current directory

Thank you @jksoegaard for the nudge.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to download the non-amalgated source code version of SQLite. It's available here:

https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

At the end you'll see "Alternative Source Code Formats", and you'll need the complete source codes.

Next you'll want to decompress the source codes and then edit the Makefile to include your `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` option.

Afterwards you can compile `sqlite3.c` with this command:

```
make sqlite3.c
```

Note that if you haven't got compilers installed, you'll want to install the Xcode Command Line Tools first.

After the command above has been run, you'll have an amalgated source code version of sqlite. This again needs to be compiled into the actual binary, you expect. You can do that with a command like this:

```
gcc shell.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl -lm -o sqlite3
```

You can find more detailed instructions on sqlite's web site here:

https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html